# Rename file based on file Content batch file

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch file that reads the description name present in the XYZ.txt file and rename that file name based on description name.

For example i have a file name called "nest.txt" and when we open the text file(nest.txt) the second line of the file name has Description(Description=Man) then the batch file should rename my XYZ.txt file as Man.txt

i have 1000 files to rename based on the above condition. Please help me

Comment: What did you try ? We will not do your homework.

Comment: show an example of TXT file.

Comment: according to what you say, you have a thousand files named "nest.txt" with different content. Really??

Comment: Hi Stephan, hope you are doing well. 

yes, we have 1000 file and each of the description name is different. based on that only i would like to rename the file. Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Renaming file based on its content using Batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370879/renaming-file-based-on-its-content-using-batch-file)

Comment: Another variant duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370879/renaming-file-based-on-its-content-using-batch-file

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1* delims==" %%i in (nest.txt) do ren XYZ.txt "%%~j.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get you started.

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%A in ('find /i "Description" "nest.txt"') do echo %%B
```

Comment: Hi All a small correction here..i apologies for the same.

For example i have a file name called "nest.txt" and when we open the text file(nest.txt) the second line of the file name has Description(Description=Man) then the batch file should rename my nest.txt file as Man.txt

Answer (score 1):

I assume, you have 1000 files with 1000 different names.

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('dir /b *.txt') do (
  for /f "skip=1 tokens=1* delims==" %%j in ( %%i ) do ( 
    if "%%j"=="Description" echo ren "%%i" "%%k.txt" 
  )
)
```

This will not work on files which have spaces in their (original) filename, but I don't understand, why. (%%i contains only the part before the first space). Maybe someone other can help with this (I'm sure, it's only a minor change, but I can't find it)

Remove the "echo", if the output fits your needs.

(are you sure that all 1000 files have 1000 different Descriptions?)