# Renaming file based on its content using Batch file

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch file that reads the description name present in the nest.txt file and rename that file name based on description name.

For example i have a file name called "nest.txt" and when we open the text file(nest.txt) the second line of the file name has Description(say Description=Man) then the batch file should rename my nest.txt file as Man.txt

Open a file nest.txt
Copy the description name present in file nest.txt

```
Header
Description=MAN
Menu KeyWords=MAN_ABC
```

Now close this file and rename file nest.txt to MAN.txt

Comment: How do you identify which files need to be opened/renamed?  For example, could it be more than one file (e.g., *.txt)?

Comment: yes we have multiple file with different file name and each file has different description. so each file should be renamed based on its description name. Please help me.

Comment: What you are asking for is not difficult, but it is problematic because using a file mask like *.txt will find files again after they are renamed.  I'll type an answer that shows you how to do what you are asking, and avoid the file mask problems.

Comment: Please provide some tips.

Comment: Would it just be those three lines or would it be more?

Comment: it has more lines, however only second line has Description name that is fixed. PLease make sure that the file name should be the same as Description name as explained in above example.

nest.txt to MAN.txt

please revert for any questions

Comment: The answer isolates the `Description=` line in the file, ignoring the other lines.  It does not do any error checking however, so I'm not sure what will happen if a file doesn't have `Description=` in it or if the value after the `=` is blank.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rename file based on file Content batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366009/rename-file-based-on-file-content-batch-file)

Comment: @Endoro More like exact duplicate.

Comment: Another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17372805/modify-file-content-using-batch-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following batch file takes one command line parameter and must be run from the folder where the files to be renamed exist.  You could easily add more code to the batch file to make it more intelligent (e.g., change to the folder, hard code `*.txt` in place of `%1`, etc.).

So, if the batch file is called `fixfilenames.bat` and is in the same folder with the TXT files, from a command prompt, type `fixfilenames *.txt` and it will rename the files first to have the extension `temp_txt` so that the `for` loop won't pick up the files again after they are renamed.  Then when it is done, it renames all `temp_txt` files to `txt` files.

```
@echo off

for %%i in (%1) do (
  for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%j in ('findstr /B /I "Description=" "%%i"') do (
    ren "%%i" "%%j.temp_txt"
  )
)

ren *.temp_txt *.txt
```

Comment: James it is working fine for normal text description however when we have a description name with the special character such as linéaire, it fails. Can you please modify and help me?

Comment: Sorry.  I don't know much about extended characters and filenames.  Try searching for extended characters, batch file, and code page.

Comment: Hey @JamesL. I came across this ans of yours while searching for a similar requirement, I am completely new to batch scripting so would you be kind enough to tell me what `for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%j` does ?

Comment: @WilfredClement : `delims==` tells the parser to take the output from `findstr /B /I "Description="` and split it on the equals sign.  The first part will therefore be "Description" and the second part will be the value after the equals sign.  `tokens=2` makes the parser assign the second value (the part after the equal sign) to `%%j`.  You can use `%%j` in the `do` section of the `for` statement.  In this case, the OP wanted to rename the file (`%%i.txt`) to be a new filename (`%%j.txt`).