# Renaming text files using a string in their content

Tags: batch-file, file-rename

I have looked in this issue in a 3 years old question but couldn't adapt the batch script to work with my case: [Rename text files based on multiple strings in their contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23095874/rename-text-files-based-on-multiple-strings-in-their-contents)

This is what my text files contains:

```
<!-- ===============================================
TEXT TEXT"
===============================================
An : ONE
Ca : ONE - AVRIL 2016 
Site : example.com -->

<!--===============================================
Insertion : example.com - Bannières Mobile 300X250 VF (300x250)
```

I want to rename every file with what the line `Insertion :` contains. In my example it would be : `example.com - Bannières Mobile 300X250 VF (300x250)`

I tried to use this script and since it used Date and Time it the original question but I don't know how to make it work

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM for all files do:
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
  REM get desired lines and set variables:
  for /f "tokens=2,4 delims=:" %%i in (' findstr "^Insertion" %%f') do set %%i=%%j
  REM construct filename:
  set "name=!Insertion!.txt"
  echo Filename is: "!name!"
)
```

Can someone please help me adapting the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this will do:

```bat
For /F "Tokens=1,2*Delims=:" %%A In ('FindStr/LBIC:"Insertion : " *.txt'
) Do For /F "Tokens=*" %%D In ("%%~C"
) Do If Not Exist "%%~D%%~xA" Ren "%%A" "%%~D%%~xA"
```

If you get cyclic issues, *(loop reading the files it's just renamed)*, then add an extra little step:

```bat
For /F "Tokens=1,2*Delims=:" %%A In ('FindStr/LBIC:"Insertion : " *.txt'
) Do For /F "Tokens=*" %%D In ("%%~C"
) Do If Not Exist "%%~D%%~xA_" Ren "%%A" "%%~D%%~xA_"
Ren *.txt_ *.txt
```

Note: *If you change the `*.txt` to include a full path, you will need to adjust the tokenising to cater for the additional delimiter*.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the second code works well, the only thing is that some characters like `é` in `example.com - Bannières Mobile 300X250 VF (300x250)` shows like this `Banni├¿res`
Other than that everything is great, thank you very much for your help